# Troubleshooting my project xorg error. Services not booting

Tags: pi-2, xorg, services

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is empty i did have a `99-calibration.conf` I put in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` but I had to make the `xorg.conf.d/` dir so i migth have already messed up before.

Now starting the pi takes me to the desktop in tty7 with this error in tty0 (not the whole error)Likely this error is what causes xinitrc to fail and not start the server :

```
rc.local[339]:(ww)warning, (EE) error (NI) not implemented (??) unknown
```

Some info that migth be usefull:

I am trying to get a 4-inch LCD project working.So far i have a boot to tty7 desktop with xinitrc failing to start the backend-server and chromium.I think this migth be caused by the init scripts as seen by both nginx and fcgiwrap not running on boot as i took them directly from my project `/etc/init.d` and they migth be outdated.

**Update** with info from comments:
Running xinitrc in `/etc/rc.local` that opens chromium and a backend server and to start gui I do su- pi -c 'startx' &

Comment: Do you use `/etc/rc.local` in any way?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most error prone issues is to use deprecated `etc/rc.local`. Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it. We have seen many problems on this site if using it. An important note is the last sentence in the linked document:

> Note that there are some areas where systemd currently provides a certain amount of compatibility where we expect this compatibility to be removed eventually.

This means that your job may have run in the past but just installing another daemon or service or doing a configuration that changes the boot order of services or just doing a software upgrade may break your job. The reason is that `/etc/rc.local` does not run as last job as defined by **SysV** (now only emulated by **systemd**) and that the order of starting services isn't determined without dependencies.

So the first step of troubleshooting should be to avoid using `/etc/rc.local` in particular when starting a complex Graphical User Interface.